# Is there a way to make some formatting in Google Sheet within R

Tags: r, google-apps-script, google-sheets, googlesheets4

I'm currently on a project aiming to generate some formatted report from R to google sheet.

Now I'm using googlesheets4 package and able to write data into google sheet from R. But is there a way to do some formatting work? like **bold**, *italic*, add $ sign or conditional formatting and etc.

Here is the example spread sheet I made.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vp-w5muArvMxHKx4NL-39NMkAHRJCtldXLkUmJqKK2E/edit?usp=sharing

the output I want is like this(in sheet2), having $ in spend col, keep integer in kpi cols and conditional formatting on upsell cols

[image]

Comment: shared, please help thanks

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://community.rstudio.com/t/formatting-cells-using-googlesheets4/75605) of Jenny Bryan (author of the package)

Comment: May be worth watching this issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/googlesheets4/issues/179

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. I don't believe googlesheets4 has this type of functionality (yet at least.)

The way I (quite inefficiently) worked around this was by creating two sheets, taking advantage of the fact that it is possible to format cells that have native/google sheets functions.

The first spreadsheet contained the raw data imported from the R script,  which could not be formatted. The second sheet was formatted to my liking, then collected the first sheet's data through functions.

Hope this helps! I would have added this as a comment but I do not yet have the reputation to do so.